# Why are indexer property setters not inlined?

Tags: c#, performance, generics, unmanaged

I have a class that wraps an unmanaged allocation into an array. You can see the [source here on Github](https://github.com/Wildenhaus/Iliad/blob/master/Iliad/Memory/ArrayReference.cs), but here's the main gist of it:

```
public unsafe class ArrayReference<T> : Reference, IArrayReference<T>
  where T : unmanaged
{

  private T* typedPointer_;

  public T this[ int index ]
  {
    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    get => typedPointer_[ index ];
    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    set => typedPointer_[ index ] = value;
  }

}
```

It is pretty straightforward, and for read operations, it provides great performance (measured with BenchmarkDotNet):

```
Array size: 128
Managed byte[] ranged-for get: 69.8046 ns
ArrayReference ranged-for get: 66.7340 ns
Managed byte[] ranged-for set: 66.1855 ns
ArrayReference ranged-for set: 68.4863 ns
```

And the benchmark code:

```
[GlobalSetup]
public void Setup()
{
  median = AllocationSize / 2;
  alloc_ = new Allocation( AllocationSize );
  array_ = new ArrayReference<byte>( alloc_.Address, AllocationSize );
  managedArray_ = new byte[ AllocationSize ];
}

[Benchmark]
public void ManagedArray_ranged_for_get()
{
  var counter = 0;
  for ( var i = 0; i < AllocationSize; i++ )
    counter += managedArray_[ i ];
}

[Benchmark]
public void ArrayReference_ranged_for_get()
{
  var counter = 0;
  for ( var i = 0; i < AllocationSize; i++ )
    counter += array_[ i ];
}

[Benchmark]
public void ManagedArray_ranged_for_set()
{
  for ( var i = 0; i < AllocationSize; i++ )
    managedArray_[ i ] = ( byte ) i;
}

[Benchmark]
public void ArrayReference_ranged_for_set()
{
  for ( var i = 0; i < AllocationSize; i++ )
    array_[ i ] = ( byte ) i;
}
```

As you can see, reading from an `ArrayReference` is slightly faster because it doesn't perform a range check and it has direct access to the pointer of the array. However, **writing is slower in `ArrayReference` than it is in a managed `byte[]` array**, and it looks like the problem is that the setter isn't being inlined.

JIT x86 for Managed byte[] set:

```
managedArray_[ median ] = 0;
00007FFA237A216C  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFA237A2170  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+18h]  
00007FFA237A2174  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFA237A2178  mov         edx,dword ptr [rdx+24h]  
00007FFA237A217B  cmp         rdx,qword ptr [rax+8]  
00007FFA237A217F  jb          00007FFA237A2186  
00007FFA237A2181  call        00007FFA833DF110  
00007FFA237A2186  lea         rax,[rax+rdx+10h]  
00007FFA237A218B  mov         byte ptr [rax],0
```

JIT x86 for ArrayReference::set:

```
typedPointer_[ index ] = value;
00007FFA237A20BC  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFA237A20C0  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rcx+10h]  
00007FFA237A20C4  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
00007FFA237A20C8  mov         edx,dword ptr [rdx+24h]  
00007FFA237A20CB  xor         r8d,r8d  
00007FFA237A20CE  cmp         dword ptr [rcx],ecx  
00007FFA237A20D0  call        00007FFA237A1738  
 -> 
    00007FFA237A20F0  push        rbp  
    00007FFA237A20F1  sub         rsp,20h  
    00007FFA237A20F5  lea         rbp,[rsp+20h]  
    00007FFA237A20FA  mov         qword ptr [rbp+10h],rcx  
    00007FFA237A20FE  mov         dword ptr [rbp+18h],edx  
    00007FFA237A2101  mov         dword ptr [rbp+20h],r8d  
    00007FFA237A2105  cmp         dword ptr [7FFA23688310h],0  
    00007FFA237A210C  je          00007FFA237A2113  
    00007FFA237A210E  call        00007FFA833DD3E0  
    00007FFA237A2113  mov         rax,qword ptr [rbp+10h]  
    00007FFA237A2117  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+20h]  
    00007FFA237A211B  mov         edx,dword ptr [rbp+18h]  
    00007FFA237A211E  movsxd      rdx,edx  
    00007FFA237A2121  mov         ecx,1  
    00007FFA237A2126  movsxd      rcx,ecx  
    00007FFA237A2129  imul        rdx,rcx  
    00007FFA237A212D  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rbp+20h]  
    00007FFA237A2130  mov         byte ptr [rax+rdx],cl
```

I don't see why this isn't being inlined. It's doing the exact same thing as a managed array would do, except with a pointer to unmanaged memory. Is this violating one of the CLR's inlining rules, or is it possibly not being inlined because `T` is generic, even though it's constrained?

Windows 10 Pro, 64-bit
.Net Core 2.2, Release Mode 64-bit RyuJIT

Comment: Use [Ildasm.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler) to obtain the IL, and analyze that.

Comment: .NET Core or Framework? Which version? Debug or Release build? What OS are you running on?

Comment: Really those numbers are all hard to believe. At 4GHz, one cycle is 0.25ns, and while modern CPUs can perform multiple operations in the same cycle, 20 get operations per cycle is unrealistic.

Comment: Show us your timing code.

Comment: @harold The benchmark is setting the same value to the same array index. It definitely explains the unrealistic timing (which evens out with the range-based for loop benchmarks), but it doesn't explain why the JIT isn't handling pointer write operations efficiently.

Comment: You are just not measuring what you think you are.  A memory read that is never used has no side-effects, so can be eliminated.  A memory write cannot, that might affect code running in other threads.  Or to put it another way, the jitter optimizer treats pointer writes as volatile.  You'll need a more realistic usage of your class to measure its real benefit.

Comment: @HansPassant You're right, those benchmarks are skewed, and I threw them out. Comparing them to the for loop read/write tests (which are still in the post), they do add up though. Digging through the disassembly though, the problem with writes is that the setter is not being inlined, and I'm wondering whether its a problem with being generic or unsafe.

Comment: I tried reproing this both on 2.2 and current coreclr master and in both `set_Item` is getting inlined. Happy to retry on your actual case if you send me a pointer to it.